# How do MVVM architecture and Reso Coder's clean architecture differ from each other for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mvvm, clean-architecture

I am confused to understand differences between "MVVM architecture" and "Reso Coder's clean architecture". I have seen clean architecture versions in different GitHub repos. But I cannot decide which is the best to organize your app architecture. Here is what I mean.

### Reso Coder's clean architecture

[image: Reso Coder's clean architecure]

He divided application into three main parts.

There can be different approaches of course. In GitHub, some projects have similar architecture with Reso Coder and others have similar with MVVM.

So, what are the differences and similarities between these two architectures?

Answer (score 1):

Clean Architecture and MVVM are in the same concept but the level of their implementations are quite different.

Clean Architecture is talking about some rules to architect your software in the highest level of abstraction.

But [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) is just an architectural pattern, which can be implemented in a part of the software (close to the view).

In general, any software that wants to be scalable should have an architecture (not necessary for small software) but MVVM could be used to any scale of software.